# how can i filter data in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with two fields, one refers to the gender and the other to the city.

The user must type the city, the file has 100 lines with various names repeated, how can I filter this data by city?

```
list
gender,City
M,Barcelona
M,London
M,Antwerpen
M,Paris
F,Calgary
F,Calgary
F,Albertville
F,Albertville
F,Lillehammer
F,Lillehammer
```

---

```
import csv

with open('dados_resposta.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    cidade = []
    mulheres = []
    for row in readCSV:
        Sex = row[0]
        City = row[1]

        cidade.append(City)
        mulheres.append(Sex)

    entrada = input('country: ')
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: if the user types 'Albertville' I want it to return to another row with all values equal to 'Albertville'
list = ['F','F']

Comment: Surely [one of these posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+filter+csv) will help

Comment: That's not "genre", that's "gender".  The `csv` module can read this into a list of lists.  From there, you can extract the records you want.

Comment: Why don't you try to use a pandas Dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Ask for the city first, then loop and filter using an if statement

```
import csv

entrada = input('city: ')

mulheres = []

with open('dados_resposta.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        Sex = row[0]
        if row[1] == entrada:
            mulheres.append(Sex)

print('Genders for {} are {}'.format(entrada, mulheres))
```

Alternatively, [use pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html)

Comment: You're not appending to `cidade`

Comment: @Barmar According to comments, that wasn't wanted

Comment: Right.  If you're only looking for "Barcelona", there's no point in tracking multiple copies of "Barcelona".

Comment: That makes sense. The other list was only necessary if you're filtering after reading everything. Although in general, it's easier to make an array of dictionaries or tuples rather than multiple arrays that need to be in sync.